# Show a Bootstrap Modal onLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, templates

Have a series of page.handlebars that load dynamically into a {{{body}}} of a main layout.

On redirect of a page to certain pages, would like to show a Bootstrap Modal onLoad.

This would need to be within the body of the page, and the modalID is loaded dynamically.

This would seem to be correct, but what needs to be tweaked for it to work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#{{activate.[0]}}').modal('show')
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You can pass a html string as a parameter, but take a look at this [sample](http://jsbin.com/upINuh/3/edit?html,output) to see the diference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. I tried this.

```
$('#multi-file-dropzone-js').modal('show');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either read the id of modal in your javascript directly from the model files and then use it to open the modal. Or you can render the id in some hidden div(using handlebar) and can read the contents of that div and open the modal.

You can't use handlebar tags inside your js code.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CkAcL/

js

```
var source   = $("#a").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var context = {modalid: "#mymodalid"};
var html    = template(context);

function openModal(){
 var mymodalid=$("#modalid").html();
    // use $(mymodalid).show();
}

//call openModal() inside your document.ready()
```

Comment: Neat technique.. Turns out, handlebar tags did work inside the js code.. Had called the bootstrap .js files after the body though, so the modal js and jquery had yet to be reached.. Moved that, and it worked.. Thanks for the js insight though!